# Scope of \addfontfeature

Tags: fontspec

I have encountered something while using `fontspec` that I do not quite understand. What is the scope of a font feature added using the `\addfontfeatures` command? For instance, consider the example below using `lualatex`:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{fontspec,lipsum}
 \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}

 \begin{document}

 1234567890

 {%
      \addfontfeatures{Numbers=OldStyle}%
      1234567890%
 }

 1234567890

 Here is some text that is long enough so that it will involve a single proper hyphenation at the end of the first line.

 {%
      \addfontfeatures{HyphenChar=None}%
      Here is some text that is long enough so that it will involve a single proper hyphenation at the end of the first line.%
 }

 Here is some text that is long enough so that it will involve a single proper hyphenation at the end of the first line.

 \end{document}
```

The option `Numbers=OldStyle` is only applied locally and does not exit the braces, but the option `HyphenChar=None` continues after the braces end. Is there a way to limit the scope of `HyphenChar` as `Numbers` is limited above?

Comment: Hmmmm, I guess all this needs to be added explicitly to the documentation :-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Good question!

Some assignments performed by TeX (and also by XeTeX) are *always global*. You find the list on page 277 of the TeXbook or section 10.2 in TeX by Topic. Among them is setting the `\hyphenchar` of a font, which is the primitive operation performed by the

```
HyphenChar=None
```

option, or any other setting of the same key.

So, no, there is no way to limit the scope of that declaration. Simply declaring a new font family using the same font but changing the hyphenchar will not work, as the value is associated to the memory location relative to the font and fonts loading the same TFM file (standard TeX) or the same OTF file (XeTeX) will share the hyphenchar.

A possible workaround is to define a new font family slightly scaling the font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Junicode}
\newfontfamily{\mainno}[HyphenChar=None,Scale=.999]{Junicode}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{latin}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\textwidth=5cm

\begin{document}

\hyphenpenalty=-3000

{\mainno\the\hyphenchar\font\lipsum*[2]} \the\hyphenchar\font \lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

The settings are just to encourage hyphenation. The first part of the paragraph will have no hyphens and start with `-1`, while the second part will be hyphenated and start with `45`. Of course the first part will have many overfull lines. Here's an image (second part truncated):

[image]

It's also possible to say

```
{\addfontfeatures{Scale=.999,HyphenChar=None}\the\hyphenchar\font\lipsum*[2]}
\the\hyphenchar\font \lipsum[3]
```

Comment: Well, with `\aftergroup` and some bookkeeping, `fontspec` could (and maybe should) take care of (re)setting the hyphenchar.

Comment: @Robert TeX uses only one value of `\hyphenchar` for each font, the one current at the end of the paragraph. When TeX splits a paragraph into lines, it has forgotten about grouping structures and is just confronted with a horizontal list. And defining a new font family doesn't help either, because the hyphenchar is associated to the memory location for the font information and fonts corresponding to the same TFM file (or OTF or TTF in case of XeTeX) can't have different hyphenchars.

Comment: after reading the surrounding material in the TeXbook it makes a lot more sense now...perhaps a note about HypenChar should be included in the `fontspec` documentation. The `addfontfeatures` command is introduced in the context of using it for local modifications, which is what prompted this question in the first place.

Comment: @grizzilus I've added a hack, which shouldn't be too noticeable (the font is scaled at 99.9%).

Comment: That works really well, quite clever.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about the paragraph scope of hyphenchar. But with `pdftex`, it could be done like this: `\pdfcopyfont\newfont\font \hyphenchar\newfont=-1`. For some reason, this doesn't work in `luatex`, however, while `xetex` doesn't know `pdfcopyfont` or any equivalent.

Comment: @Robert In my experiment, `\pdfcopyfont` works the same in `pdftex` and `luatex`. There's no analog in `xetex`

Comment: Really? The following works for me with `pdftex`, but not with `luatex`: ``\hsize=11em
\def\x{hyphenchar }
\x\x\x\x\x
{\pdfcopyfont\newfont\font\newfont\hyphenchar\font=`=
\x\x\x\x}\x\x\x
\bye``

Comment: @Robert Curious; it works if you say `\hyphenchar=-1`, but not if you say `\hyphenchar=64` (or any other number). Seems like a bug in LuaTeX.

Comment: @egreg Indeed..

Answer (score 2):

I just came across a similar problem, where I was not able to limit the scope of `\addfontfeature{WordSpace=0.8}`, which I found weird, as in some other place I had it working already, limited by a pair of parentheses. In that other place though I had also adjusted the letter space, so I came up with the solution of adding a `LetterSpace=0` to my `\addfontfeature`, which doesn't have any effect on the letter space, but helps to keep the word space setting local. The same works also with the OP's example:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{fontspec,lipsum}
 \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}

 \begin{document}

 1234567890

 {%
      \addfontfeatures{Numbers=OldStyle}%
      1234567890%
 }

 1234567890

 Here is some text that is long enough so that it will involve a single proper hyphenation at the end of the first line.

 {%
      \addfontfeatures{HyphenChar=None,LetterSpace=0}%
      %\addfontfeatures{HyphenChar=None}%
      Here is some text that is long enough so that it will involve a single proper hyphenation at the end of the first line.%
 }

 Here is some text that is long enough so that it will involve a single proper hyphenation at the end of the first line.

 \end{document}
```

[image: example output]