# \addfontfeature resets \prehyphenchar and \posthyphenchar

Tags: luatex, fontspec, hyphenation, polyglossia, opentype

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87073/scope-of-addfontfeature) is similar, but applies only to X<sub>E</sub>T<sub>E</sub>X.

In LuaT<sub>E</sub>X, `\prehyphenchar` and `\posthyphenchar` supposedly affect the current language:

> All languages start out with `` \prehyphenchar=`\- ``, `\posthyphenchar=0`, `\preexhyphenchar=0` and `\postexhyphenchar=0`. When you assign the values of one of these four parameters, you are actually changing the settings for the current `\language`, this behaviour is compatible with `\patterns` and `\hyphenation`.
>   ([LuaT<sub>E</sub>X Reference v1.0.7](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/doc/luatex/luatex.pdf), section 4.4)

However, after changing `\addfontfeature`, both of those reset to the defaults. Can the hyphenation characters be made permanent? How?

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\textwidth}{17em}

\RequirePackage{lipsum}

\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{cmunrm.otf}

\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\addto\captionsenglish{\prehyphenchar=`¶ \posthyphenchar=`¶}
\prehyphenchar=`¶ \posthyphenchar=`¶

\begin{document}

\begin{english}
\lipsum*[1]\par
{\addfontfeature{Path}---any feature: hyphen reset---}\par
\lipsum*[1]\par
\end{english}

\end{document}
```

[image: PDF output]

Comment: fontspec (re)set the values in `\__fontspec_init:`. Imho this is wrong for luatex, as there the values are tied to languages and not fonts. Open an issue in the github repo of fontspec.

Comment: [I created an issue here.](https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/344)